# Facebook graph api GraphMethodException (code 100) with valid access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting a 400 error from a facebook api request

> https://graph.facebook.com/[post id]?access_token=

```
{"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}
```

The access token is valid as I can issue other graph api requests. I can't find any documentation that describes what this error indicates. Looking back through all the posts for the facebook page, I can't find this post id, so it appears that it was deleted. I would expect to get a 404 response if it doesn't exist. I'm posting this question to see if anyone else gets this error and if it's consistent with a deleted post.

Comment: It seems like the response FB sends if the post doesn't exist(There maybe more cases). Tested it here - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Judging from the other answers I found in SO, it seems this error also shows up if the a/c you're requesting from, doesn't have the permission to read the post.